# How to import existing collection from MongoDB and Perform operation it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get Data from my existing collection and perform some operation on it,
hear what i tried

```
//for getting existing data
var Vvin = new mongoose.Schema({});
const VS = mongoose.model('V',Vvin,'vs');
```

Above code is working but now comes issue

```
//To perform operation
app.get('/get', (req,res) => {
VS.find({vWebsite : '123'},(error,result) => {
    if(error){
        res.json(error)
    }else{
        res.json(result);
    }
})
```

it is returning all data without filtering ***vWebsite*** but if i use ***_id*** it's work properly

Comment: @LucaPizzini var Vvin = new mongoose.Schema({ ... }); throwing an error, any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Try `const result  = await VS.findOne({vWebsite : '123'});`.

Also remember to make your function `async`.

Comment: implemented that                                                                                                
`app.get('/get', async(req,res) => {
   await VS.findOne({vWebsite:'123'}).then((error,data) => {
        if (error) {
            res.json(error);
        }else{
            res.json(data);
            console.log(result);
        }
    })

})`   but isn't working, i am getting whole collection where there is nothing data that matches **vWebsite:123**